# tablesorter jquery get sum of numeric column after being filtered

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm developing with tablesorter jquery, my question is:

is there a way to show the sum of numeric column after being filtered?

for example:

+++++++++++
name-           money
+++++++++++
alan-           10
alan-           10
alan-           10
alan-           10
john-           10
john-           10
john-           10

sum of money: 70

if i filter for name and just show 'alan' i wanna get this:

+++++++++++
name-           money
+++++++++++
alan-           10
alan-           10
alan-           10
alan-           10

sum of money: 40

thanks for your help :)

Comment: sure.. do you have an example to work off of?

Comment: i didn't understood your comment! do you mean abt my real example?

Comment: your real example or an simple example that functions like yours

Comment: the example that i put on the thread is very similar! if u ask me about that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this... here is the HTML from [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2321/):

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Money</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>

</table>Sum of Money: <span class="total"></span>
```

and the necessary script:

```
$('table')
    .on('initialized filterEnd', function(){
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find('tbody tr:visible').each(function(){
            // find money in 2nd column
            total += parseFloat( $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() );
        });
        $('.total').text(total);
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['filter']
    });
```